# jQuery .change doesn't work when trying to populate 2 select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to populate 2 HTML dropdowns using PHP, MySQL and jQuery. The second one (area)'s options will depend on the selection in the first dropdown (city). I copied the code from another working project of mine but I cannot get it to work in this project.

Here is my JavaScript code (ajax.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#city").change(function() {
    var cityid = $(this).val();
    if(cityid != "") {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/inc/get.php',
        data: {cityid:cityid},
        success: function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#area").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#area").html("<option selected disabled>Bir şehir seçiniz</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

get.php file:

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if(isset($_POST['cityid'])){
  $cityid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cityid']);
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `areas` WHERE `city`='.$cityid.' and `active`=1';
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysql_error());

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<option selected disabled>Bölge seçiniz</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
    }
  }
  else {
      echo '<option selected disabled>asdBir şehir seçiniz</option>';
  }

}
?>
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="city" class=" form-control-label">Şehir</label>
    <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
      <option selected disabled>Şehir Seçin</option>
      <?php
        $qry = 'select * from `cities` where `active`=1';
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'"';
            if($_GET['d3'] == $row->id){echo ' selected';}
            echo '>'.$row->name.'</option>';
          }
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="area" class=" form-control-label">Bölge</label>
    <select id="area" name="area" class="form-control">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked the network section in dev tools and ajax.js loads just fine. Though when I select a value in the city dropdown, nothing happens. It doesn't call the get.php file at all. I have been searching everywhere for hours now and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried installing Fiddler and seeing what response (if any) you are getting back from your Ajax call? https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `.change()` function and single-step through it, to see what's happening when you select from the first menu.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to define an `error` handler in your AJAX settings object, either. Something as simple as `error: function ( jqXHR, status, error ) { console.log( 'Error!', error ) }` might help.

Comment: @trfletch unfortunately nothing changed at all in Fiddler when I selected an option in the first dropdown. 

Also I just realized that the console outputs "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" on the first line of ajax.js

Comment: Are you referencing the Jquery script in you page?

Comment: @trfletch yes, the first code block I mentioned in the question

Comment: What I mean is do you have a reference to the jquery core file on your page somewhere, for example: <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @trfletch oh my bad. Yes, of course. I tried both using cdn and hosting it local but neither way changed anything. I could see the jquery file loading in the network section in both cases

Comment: Does the `<script>` that references (and, therefore, potentially _loads_) your `ajax.js` appear before the `<script>` that references jQuery?

Comment: @ItoPizarro jQuery is called before any other js and my ajax.js is called the last

Comment: What other JavaScript libraries are you using?

Comment: You can read more about [jQuery.noConflict() here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) and post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed it by adding the following line to the first line of my ajax.js file:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And then changed every `$` with `$jq` in the same ajax.js file. I hope this helps other people as well